# SWIFT URL String build

Tags: swift, xcode, url

How do I build the URL as below:

```
/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZTM_FOR_MOBILITY_SRV/BusinessPartnerSet('BP-CR-EM01')/?$format=json
```

I want specifically the part - BusinessPartnerSet('BP-CR-EM01').

BP-CR-EM01 value is dynamic value.

```
let newUrl = url  + "'\(businessPartners[myIndex].partnerId)'"
```

url has the fixed URL and the + operator followed by dynamic value. Please help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use `URLComponents`

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "http://mycompany.com")!
components.path = "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZTM_FOR_MOBILITY_SRV/BusinessPartnerSet('\(businessPartners[myIndex].partnerId)')/"
components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "$format", value:"json")]
if let url = components.url {
    print(url)
    // or if you need the string
    print(url.absoluteString)
}
```

Comment: Yes this helped perfectly. Thanks alot.